# Code is not Word Wrapping in .wl MMA file

Tags: front-end, formatting, packages

Is there any way to word wrap the code in .wl file extensions? When I select `Format > WordWrapping > Wrap at Window Width` in a .wl file, it extends the block and doesn't word wrap the code. Thank you.

Comment: Highlight the cell bracket you are typing in and right click, under "Style" change it from "Code" to "Input".  If you want to start a new "Input" cell, put the cursor in between cells and hit Cmd-9 (may be Ctrl-9 on a non-Mac)

Comment: Will users who use my program have to do this every time when they look at the code in my package?

Comment: No, it seems that the package saves the style for a given cell.  Here is a .wl package I just created and saved, with 2 "Input" cells and one "Code" cell.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/8ynDF.png  - so it will remember what the style is for a given cell.

Comment: if you do that, the code will actually be commented, that means it will not be loaded when doing a `Get` for that file. If you use the .wl files just as a lightweigt text-version of notebooks that might be fine, but if you plan to load the file as a package then you might need to additionally make those "Input"-style cells to initialization cells (which "Code" cells are automatically by style definitions)... (I have not tried that with .wl files but know that the behavior is like that for .m files, please correct me if .wl files behave different...)

Comment: @AlbertRetey, you are correct. If I convert the style to Input from Code in .wl files, I cannot use `Get` or `Needs` to call the package.  Do you know how to word wrap text in Code format?

Comment: as I wrote: every cell that has the option `InitializationCell` set to `True` will be written uncommented to the package file and thus loaded with `Get`. All other input and text cells will be written as comments, generated cells will be discarded. In the default style sheet "Code" cells do have `InitializationCell` set to `True` but `Input` cells don't. If you want an input cell to be written uncommented you just need to set that option to true. Of course it might make more sense to define your own style for packages, where you could do that by default.